# Как выбрать option в select по значению?

Tags: html, html5, angular2, typescript, html-select

Возможно ли указать значение `option`, которое будет выбираться по умолчанию при загрузке страницы? Пробовал через `selected` и  `selected="selected"`. Результат нулевой.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="typeSearch">
   <option [ngValue]="1" selected>Названию</option>
   <option [ngValue]="2">Автору</option>
   <option [ngValue]="3">Типу</option>
   <option [ngValue]="4">Расширению</option>
</select>
```

[image: select]

Comment: похоже на Angular, если он используется - то стоит это указать

Comment: @Grundy , не думал, что это имеет значение. Исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по разметке - используется Angular.

При связывании через `ngModel` выбирается `option` чье значение совпадает со значением `typeSearch`.

Таким образом достаточно просто присвоить этой переменной или свойству нужное значение.

Comment: Все работает, благодарю)

Answer (score 2):

Можешь обойти циклом все значения `select` и применить порядковый номер соответствующего `option` (значение `option` совпадает с нужным значением) к `select` через `selectedIndex`.

### Пример:

```js
var defaultValue = "Расширению";
var yourSelect = document.querySelector('.form-control');

for (let i, j = 0; i = yourSelect.options[j]; j++) {
  if (i.value == defaultValue) {
    yourSelect.selectedIndex = j;
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="typeSearch">
  <option [ngValue]="1">Названию</option>
  <option [ngValue]="2">Автору</option>
  <option [ngValue]="3" selected='selected'>Типу</option>
  <option [ngValue]="4">Расширению</option>
</select>
```

Если нужного значения в `select` нет, то будет выбрано значение `selected` или же самое первое (при отсутствии `selected`).

Comment: Удивительно, я проверил этот код на отдельно взятой html странице, так же в онлайн компиляторе. И да, там это решение работает, ровно, как и атрибут selected. Но в моем случае это видимо не вариант.

Comment: @АртёмБондарев я не правильно вас понял.

Comment: да, это моя ошибка. В любом случае, ответ может кому-нибудь пригодиться)